# pyenv installation script: need help understanding what it does

Tags: bash, pyenv

One of the steps to [install pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) requires typing the following into a terminal:

```
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

While I understand what `echo -e` and `>> ./bash_profile` do, I do not really understand what is going on inside the quotations marks.

After running  the command above, my `bash_profile` now has the following:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

**Question:** Could you explain what this code does? Is my interpretation of what is happening (see below) correct?

Interpretation:

- `command -v` takes the name of a command and outputs its description, if the command given does not exist nothing is outputted; thus `command -v pyenv` will output the description `pyenv` if it is available (which will be if you installed `pyenv`), otherwise it will not show anything
- the `1>/dev/null` takes the output of the `command -v pyenv` and throws it away
- What is the purpose for `2>&1`?
- Why do we need the `eval` inside the if block? Can't we just run `pyenv init -` directly?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: If -1 add an explanation so that I can either update the question or remove it.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections for `2>&1`.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution for `$(` `)`.